# how to display path with FriendlyId, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, friendly-id

My task is to be able to see the path of the current category or product in browsing bar.

At this moment I just can see current category like this

localhost:3000/categories/smalcinataji

but I want like this

localhost:3000/categories/atkritumu-parstrades-tehnika/smalcinataji

To create pretty urls I am using gem called FriendlyId from this example http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast

Thanks!

Comment: Does Someone have done something like this, give me just the tip :) Thanks

Comment: what is this? atkritumu-parstrades-tehnik

Comment: @Said Kaldybaev  . Im sorry atkritumu-parstrades-tehnika is main category and smalcinataji is a subcategory. It is in latvian :)

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds Could you provide some sample data and the expected output / generated URL?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt In my question, there is shown the expected output. I want like this ` /category_name/subcategory_name/product_name `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FriendlyId can take [a method to construct the slug](http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/FriendlyId/Slugged#label-Column+or+Method%3F).

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  friendly_id :category_and_subcategory

  def category_and_subcategory
    "#{my_category_method}/#{my_subcategory_method}"
  end
end
```

Note that there might be an issue with routing due to the additional slash, but there's certainly a fix for this, too, if nescessary.

Comment: Does this will work if I tell You that categorization functionality I build using gem called Ancestry ?

Comment: Well, obviously you need to adapt how the slug is built in the method, but friendly_id doesn't care where the elements for the slug come from.

Comment: I am pretty new in rails so maybe some guys have already done that so I could use it as example ? :)